# Access to divine casting with low Wisdom?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, prestige-class, bard, divine

I started a campaign with a Gnome Bard Illusionist in D&D 3.5.  As the campaign played out, due to story and circumstance, I would now like to become a Divine Trickster.  The entry requirements for Divine Trickster involve 2nd level divine casting.  I dumped Wisdom when I started my character so I can't access divine spells even when multi-classing into Cleric or other divine classes.  Is there a way for a Bard with 16 Int, 8 Wis, and 18 Cha to access the prerequisites for Divine Trickster?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As mentioned, we need to know what RPG and edition you're asking about in order to answer your question; you can indicate this by editing the corresponding tag (e.g. [dnd-3.5e] or [pathfinder-1e]) into your post. Once you do that, we can hopefully reopen the question or direct you to where it has already been answered.

Comment: There is no “divine trickster” class in D&D 3.5e—I presume you mean *Races of Stone*’s “divine prankster”? Also, what level are you currently, and is that as a single-classed bard, or as a bard/wizard (illusionist)? If the latter, what’s the breakdown?

Comment: @KRyan I have googled for Divine Trickster, and there is a [homebrew Divine Trickster](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Divine_Trickster_(3.5e_Prestige_Class)). The divine spells prereq is almost the same.

Comment: @Zachiel Requiring *spiritual weapon* would be a **massive** change that nixes a ton of the options in my answer, so if that is what was meant it would be a huge change to the question (that’s on me for answering a question before getting that clarification, though, if it happens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are several options here, and for the most part, the most important feature you should be looking for is getting those 2nd-level divine spells in as few class levels as possible, so I have organized this answer accordingly, from least class levels to most class levels.

### 2nd-level divine spells in zero class levels

There’s only one option to avoid spending *any* class levels on this, which would be ideal, but unfortunately you likely cannot use it. It is *so much better* than any other option, though, so it’s worth asking your DM about.

But while you’re asking the DM about that, you might ask the real question

#### Ask for a houserule

The DM is free to change the rules of the game as makes for the best game. The divine prankster isn’t a powerful class (at all), and it would be really fitting for your character, so maybe the game will be best if you’re allowed to *just take divine prankster*, without worrying about the prerequisites.

Seriously, if this were my game, this is what we would do.

#### Southern Magician feat (*Races of Faerûn*)

You don’t qualify for this *Races of Faerûn* feat, which requires being a human of Mulan heritage, but perhaps if you aren’t playing Faerûn your DM will waive that requirement. If so, this is your best choice—if you can cast a 2nd-level arcane spell, you can cast it as a divine spell and meet divine prankster’s requirements.

Note that divine prankster can advance bard spellcasting without any problem—nothing about the spellcasting feature specifies that you can only pick a divine spellcasting class to advance. You only need divine spellcasting to get into the class, you can ignore it after that if you want. Even if you do wind up multiclassing into some divine spellcasting class, you may very well prefer to do so, instead of advancing that class, if your bard spellcasting is better.

### 2nd-level divine spells in one class level

There isn’t any class that gets a 2nd-level divine spell at 1st level, but there are options you can take once you have 1st-level divine spells in order to get 2nd-level divine spells.

Neither of these options cares what class you use to get the 1st-level divine spells, so any of the options listed later work for that.

#### Alternative Source Spell feat (*Dragon* vol. 325)

This feat from *Dragon* vol. 325 requires that you have both arcane and divine spellcasting, and allows you to cast an arcane spell as divine and vice-versa. The idea is that if you already have 2nd-level arcane spells, you can get some divine spellcasting, take this feat, and then your ability to cast 2nd-level arcane spells as divine spells meets divine prankster’s requirements.

#### Mad Faith feat (*Heroes of Horror*)

This feat requires that you have “mild depravity,” as well as the ability to cast 1st-level divine spells, and gives you bonus divine spell slots based on your depravity. Since it requires 1st-level spell slots, it doesn’t solve issues on its own, but it does mean you could minimize how many levels it takes to get to 2nd-level spells. Moderate depravity gets you there. Unfortunately, moderate depravity has pretty painful effects that you aren’t going to like; you could get out of them, but it would require becoming undead or an evil outsider, so probably not options for you.

### 2nd-level divine spells in two class levels

Only one class gets non-Wisdom-based 2nd-level divine spells in two class levels, and for a variety of reasons it’s not probably not worth it.

#### Divine Crusader prestige class (*Complete Divine*)

This prestige class from *Complete Divine* has its own, Charisma-based spellcasting, that gets 9th-level spells in just 9 levels, which is **amazing**. On the other hand, it has some tough entry requirements (BAB +7, Weapon Focus feat), and its spell list is **just one domain**.

### 2nd-level divine spells in three class levels

Getting 2nd-level spells in three class levels is the norm; a lot of classes do that. Fewer do it without Wisdom for divine spells, but nonetheless there are options.

#### Archivist base class (*Heroes of Horror*)

Prepares divine spells up to 9th level from a “prayerbook,” much like a wizard, and is mostly Intelligence-based, for minimum ability score requirements and save DCs. Bonus spells are still Wisdom-based, though, which is a bummer.

The pair of free spells that the archivist gains every level come from the cleric spell list, but when scribing a scroll or whatever into their prayerbook, the archivist can use **any divine spell ever**, which is preposterously powerful (if your DM is ridiculously generous and includes crazy divine spell scrolls in the loot).

#### Sha’ir base class (*Dragon Compendium*)

This utterly bizarre base class from *Dragon Compendium* casts mostly-arcane spells, but also some divine spells, by having a mini-genie go and retrieve the spell from the elemental planes (...somehow?). Anyway, it uses Charisma for everything, gets 9th-level spells, and even does it “on time” (unlike sorcerer and many of the others on this list, which are delayed a level starting at 3rd).

### 2nd-level divine spells in four class levels

Spontaneous spellcasters follow the tradition of the sorcerer of falling a level behind at 3rd, only getting 2nd-level spells at 4th level and progressing on every even level from then on. This makes them dramatically worse than their prepared counterparts, who already had the advantage since prepared spellcasting is simply better.

#### Favored Soul base class(*Complete Divine*)

Uses the cleric spell list, and gets up to 9th-level spells, but is spontaneous like a sorcerer. Uses Charisma for minimum ability scores and bonus spells, but Wisdom for save DCs—so you’re going to want to focus on spells that don’t require enemies to fail saving throws, most likely buff spells.

#### Shugenja base class (*Complete Divine*)

Weird, elemental-themed priest. Spontaneous spellcaster, up to 9th-level spells, and uses purely Charisma, but the spell list is a whole lot worse than the cleric’s (and therefore the favored soul’s).

### More options

In addition to all of the above, there’s another feat that could potentially open up more options for you:

#### Dynamic Priest feat (*Legends of the Twins*)

This feat is probably not going to work: it’s third-party material (Sovereign Press), for a specific campaign setting (Dragonlance), and has a prerequisite you can’t meet without ret-con (must be taken as a 1st-level character). That said, it does open up some potentially-interesting options.

What it does is switch your bonus spells and minimum ability score requirements for one divine spellcasting class to use Charisma instead of Wisdom. This means you could use cleric or whatever else you wanted, and get all your spells with Charisma. Your save DC would suck, but that’s fine, just focus on buff spells (which tend to be better on divine spell lists anyway).

### Conclusion

Your best bet is Southern Magician if you can use it. Well, actually, your best bet is a friendly houserule allowing you to just take divine prankster levels.

If not, Alternative Source Spell is, assuming you already have 2nd-level arcane spells, the best way to cut down on how many levels you have to take to get your ability to cast 2nd-level divine spells. With that, even one level of any divine spellcasting class gets you what you need. (If you *don’t* already have 2nd-level arcane spells, you’re probably better off getting some and still using this.)

If you already have BAB +7, you could consider divine crusader, but it’s not worth waiting to qualify.

Better are sha’ir and archivist. Sha’ir is probably better for you (since archivist uses Wisdom for bonus spells), but sha’ir is *weird and awkward*, so archivist could work about as well if you want to avoid that.

Finally, Dynamic Priest opens up some more options, most notably cleric and paladin. Cleric is good because domains are good, and paladin is good because **divine grace is amazing**. But bear in mind that getting paladin spells at all is going to require a hefty four levels of paladin, which is exceptionally painful. I don’t **really** recommend that.

As a final note, it’s not actually *good*, but Dynamic Priest could also make *Complete Divine*’s temple raider of Olidammara work for this, which might be quite on-brand. Note that it has an official adaptation that should work fine for Garl Glittergold. (Temple raider of Olidammara would be a “2nd-level divine spells in three class levels” option, for the record.)